# How to Vectorize This 2D Matrix Operation?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have 2 arrays of boolean masks and I am looking to calculate an operation on every combination of two masks.

> The slow version

```
N = 10000
M = 580
masksA = np.array(np.random.randint(0,2, size=(N,M)), dtype=np.bool)
masksB = np.array(np.random.randint(0,2, size=(N,M)), dtype=np.bool)

result = np.zeros(shape=(N,N), dtype=np.float)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        result[i,j] = np.float64(np.count_nonzero(masksB[i,:]==masksB[j,:])) / M
```

> The faster version

```
for i in range(N):
    result[i,:] = np.array(np.count_nonzero(masksB[i]==masksA, axis=1), dtype=np.float64) / M
```

Can this be done even faster with a single loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's basically outer-equality comparison keeping the first of those mask axes aligned. We can leverage `matrix-multiplication` with the idea that the matrix-multiplication of the masks themselves and their simulataneous negated versions would lead us to those outer equality-summations. Hence, for the summations of equalities, simply do -

```
out = (~masksB).astype(int).dot(~masksA.T) + masksB.astype(int).dot(masksA.T)
```

Alternatively, get the `int` version and use it to get the negated version too -

```
mB = masksB.astype(int)
out = (1-mB).dot(~masksA.T) + mB.dot(masksA.T)
```

The final output would be `out/float(M)`. Or we can replace those `int` conversions with `float` ones and then divide the output by `M`.

**Timings (with N as 1000 instead) to get equality summations**

```
# Setup
In [39]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: N = 1000
    ...: M = 580
    ...: masksA = np.array(np.random.randint(0,2, size=(N,M)), dtype=np.bool)
    ...: masksB = np.array(np.random.randint(0,2, size=(N,M)), dtype=np.bool)

# Approach #1 with int dtype converison
In [40]: %timeit (~masksB).astype(int).dot(~masksA.T) + masksB.astype(int).dot(masksA.T)
1 loop, best of 3: 870 ms per loop

# Approach #1 with float dtype converison
In [41]: %timeit (~masksB).astype(float).dot(~masksA.T) + masksB.astype(float).dot(masksA.T)
10 loops, best of 3: 74 ms per loop

# Approach #2 with int dtype converison
In [42]: %%timeit
    ...: mB = masksB.astype(int)
    ...: out = (1-mB).dot(~masksA.T) + mB.dot(masksA.T)
1 loop, best of 3: 882 ms per loop

# Approach #2 with float dtype converison
In [43]: %%timeit
    ...: mB = masksB.astype(float)
    ...: out = (1-mB).dot(~masksA.T) + mB.dot(masksA.T)
10 loops, best of 3: 59.3 ms per loop
```

So, the preferred way would be to go with the float conversion on the second approach and divide the output by `M`.

**Use one matrix-multiplication with stacking**

Since the equality summations would essentially be `int` numbers, we can use a lower precision dtype for the matrix-multiplication. Also, one more idea would be to stack the original masks with their negated versions and then perform the matrix-multiplication. Hence, for equality summations, we would have -

```
m1 = np.hstack((masksA,~masksA))
m2 = np.hstack((masksB,~masksB))
out = m2.astype(np.float32).dot(m1.T)
```

Timings (same setup as earlier) -

```
In [49]: %%timeit
    ...: m1 = np.hstack((masksA,~masksA))
    ...: m2 = np.hstack((masksB,~masksB))
    ...: out = m2.astype(np.float32).dot(m1.T)
10 loops, best of 3: 36.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is by far the quickest method. Edited to include the `/ M` as desired.

Answer (score 2):

We can effectively cut @Divakar's (current) best time in two by using only one matrix multiplication:

```
import numpy as np

N = 1000
M = 580
masksA = np.array(np.random.randint(0,2, size=(N,M)), dtype=np.bool)
masksB = np.array(np.random.randint(0,2, size=(N,M)), dtype=np.bool)

def f_pp():
    return np.where(masksB,1.0,-1.0)@np.where(masksA,0.5/M,-0.5/M).T+0.5

def f_pp_2():
    return (np.where(masksB,1.0,-1.0)@np.where(masksA,0.5,-0.5).T+0.5*M)*(1/M)

def f_dv_2():
    mB = masksB.astype(float)
    return ((1-mB).dot(~masksA.T) + mB.dot(masksA.T))*(1/M)

assert np.allclose(f_pp(),f_dv_2())
assert np.all(f_pp_2()==f_dv_2())

from timeit import timeit

print("PP     ",timeit(f_pp,number=100)*10,"ms")
print("PP 2   ",timeit(f_pp_2,number=100)*10,"ms")
print("Divakar",timeit(f_dv_2,number=100)*10,"ms")
```

Sample run:

```
PP      31.41063162125647 ms
PP 2    31.757128546014428 ms
Divakar 63.400797033682466 ms
```

How does it work? By mapping True and False to opposite numbers `x` and `-x` (a different `x` can be used for the two factors; let's say `a` for masksA and `b` for masksB) we get in the dot product a term `ab` for each position where the masks agree and a term `-ab` for each position where they are different. If `k` is the number of equal bits between a pair vectors then their dot product will be `kab-(M-k)ab = 2kab - Mab`. Choosing `a` and `b` such that `2Mab = 1` this becomes `k/M - 1/2` which is up to a constant offset our desired result.

Comment: This is really fast but the result is not identical, though 90%+ of entries are? is there like a hidden float issue?

Comment: @user1581390 I wouldn't call it an issue. It's perfectly normal with floats to get slightly different results with different algos. And the differences are really tiny.

Comment: @user1581390 In case it puts your mind at rest, I've added a variant that gives (In my limited tests) the exact same results as Divakar's method 2. It is only minimally slower than the original.